# Can I use $in with skip, limit in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, limit, skip

Using mongoose in nodejs, I want to find some data just like :

```
 var idnos = [1,2,3,.....] // an id array      
 var users = yield users.find({idno:{$in: idnos}}).sort({_id: -1}).skip(skip).limit(limit);
```

Is it ok to use $in? I am afraid that data will random become the idnos is an array. I test it and it work. BUt I still confuse.

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation is correct. There is no restriction to use `$in` with `skip`, `limit` in mongodb. If you want to clear your confusion completely then you can review how `$in`, `skip` and `limit` work in mongodb.

[Documentation for `$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/operator/query/in/)

[Documentation for `skip`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/skip/)

[Documentation for `limit`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/)

As, you are sorting the result. You should take a look at the [sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/)

For this kind of scenario, [explain()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.explain/) in mongodb is very powerful. It returns information on the query plan for the following operations: 
aggregate(); count(); distinct(); find(); group(); remove(); and update() methods.

So, you can use `explain()` and see the information...

```
db.users.explain().find({idno:{$in: idnos}}).sort({_id: -1}).skip(skip).limit(limit);
```